# IOS vfr reader page bar thumb is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, vfr-reader

I am using vfr reader in my project to read pdf files. There is no problem with showing different pdf files. However, main page bar showing the previews of pages of the first document that I loaded. Also,the thumbnail which is displayed before the CATiledLayer starts to render the PDF page is also not refreshing. It must be a caching problem but I couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the Caches folder in App directory. After that the problem is solved.